# How to check multiple selectors via jq?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

## I want a reaction when all three checkboxes are checked, but not when even one isn't checked.

Sample:

"#cBox1, #cBox2, #cBox3 are checked = Consol.log('checked');"

"Just #cBox1, #cBox3 are checked = Consol.log('NOT checked');"

I've already tried the following, without the right result:
*`if($('#cBox01, #cBox02, #cBox03')`*

```
<div id="cBoxes">
  <form>
    <input id="cBox01" class="cBox" type="checkbox" name="cBox01" value="cBox01"> checkbox 1<br>
    <input id="cBox02" class="cBox" type="checkbox" name="cBox02" value="cBox02"> checkbox 2<br>
    <input id="cBox03" class="cBox" type="checkbox" name="cBox03" value="cBox03"> checkbox 3<br>
  </form>
</div>
```

```
$('.cBox').change( function(){
  if($('#cBox01' && '#cBox02' && '#cBox03').is(':checked')){
    console.log('checked');
  }else {
    console.log('NOT checked');
  }
});
```

I got the right result after #cBox3 is checked but just for this one and not for all of them.

## Many thanks to Taplar this works for me:

```
$('.cBox').change( function(){
  if($('.cBox:checked').length === 3){
    console.log('checked');
  }else {
    console.log('NOT checked');
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('selector1, selector2, selector3')` is correct.  `$('selector' && 'selector')` is **not**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the checked on each one and check the length

```
$('#cBox01:checked, #cBox02:checked, #cBox03:checked').length === 3
```

Or you can filter and check the length

```
$('#cBox01, #cBox02, #cBox03').filter(':checked').length === 3
```

Or you can check for the inverse

```
!$('#cBox01, #cBox02, #cBox03').is(':not(:checked)')
```

In your case, since they all have a shared class, you can reduce this to

```
!$('.cBox').is(':not(:checked)')
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!